# two and's when using "between"

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an introduction part for my research paper. I wrote a sentence that follows:

"The main concern of this study is to find out whether there is a relationship **between gender and success and interest** for different disciplines taught in the FLE department of METU"

In the sentence, I want to mean "gender" as being one part and "success and interest" being the other part. If I use two ands like this, it creates an ambiguity. How can I rewrite this?

Comment: I don't like using *between* for more than two items, so I'd render that as **are relationships among gender, success and interest**. Just my two cents.

Comment: @JimMack - OP has stated there are two Items: *1. gender* and *2. success and interest*

Comment: … between on the one hand gender, and on the other success and interest. Not exactly pretty, but unambiguous.

Comment: @Jim - Yikes, I drove right by that one...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, your comment is the only viable answer to this question; why not post it as such? I know that short simple answers are generally disdained on this site, but, as long as the question is not deleted, isn't it better that it be answered correctly, rather than left unanswered, or answered incorrectly?

Comment: A recognised device to demarcate a bound couple within an and-joined list is to use the ampersand: '[A] + [B + C]' ↔ 'A and B & C'.  Commas may also be used: ' ... to find out whether there is a relationship between gender, and success and interest, ...'.

Comment: @Edin Ashworth: The ampersand is precisely what came first to my mind. To convey the same when spoken, one option without completely rewording could be to state it as "A and B-plus-C".  Onto an aside: in the particular example OP provides I think it would be apt for the study to focus on 'B' and 'C' distinctly, instead of jointly, with respect to A (and perhaps with also respect to eachother—why not?, it's not a huge list of attributes). Strictly speaking, the the correct logical parsing intended is seemingly (based on OP) "A | {B &or C}"; yet in actuality, likely desire ordered: "A | ⟨B, C⟩".

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to reword:

> The main concern of this study is to find out **whether/how gender is related to
> success and interest** for different disciplines taught...

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid ambiguity by writing:

> whether there is a relationship **between** *gender* **and** *success **[coupled with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coupled)** interest*...

or

> whether there is a relationship **between** *gender* **and** ***both** success **and** interest*...

Of course, the contrasting conjunctive adverbs ***[on the one hand, on the other hand](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_o&page=9Sg5oqrjCxPs.html)*** are also possible as indicated in the comments, but then the sentence can be heavy: these adverbs express contrast in too many words which might eclipse too much the elements compared.

Answer (score -2):

I would handle it like a list:

> "The main concern of this study is to find out whether there is a relationship **between gender, success, and interest(s?) for different disciplines taught in the FLE department of METU**"

Also, the terms "success" and, especially, "interest(s?)" seem ambiguous or unclear. There might be more specific phrasing you could use, depending on the context.

Comment: OP has stated there are two Items: *1. gender* and *2. success and interest*

Comment: good point. deleting :)